# How to combine rows of strings into one using pandas in a table or how to concatenate different rows of a column in a sentence using python?

Tags: python, string, pandas, split, concatenation

**Input:**

```
LineNo  word_num    left    top  width  text
1       1           322     14   14     My
1       2           304     4    41     Name
1       3           322     5    9      is
1       4           316     14   20     Raghav
2       1           420     129  34     Problem 
2       2           420     31   27     just
2       3           420     159  27     got
2       4           431     2    38     complicated
1       1           322     14   14     #40
1       2           304     4    41     @gmail.com   
2       1           420     129  34     2019 
2       2           420     31   27     January
```

As you can see there are columns *lineNo*, **left**, **top** and *word_num*, so I was trying if I can get some logic using these both maybe I can achieve my solution.

I wanted to do some tweaks in the output, actually this output is coming through a PDF after its converted into an image, so it is catching the whole line because of which whole line is coming and the output is not making sense, what i am thinking of doing now is to group the text in a meaning full way. For e.g
lets say this output i am getting by using this:

g = df['line_num'].ne(df['line_num'].shift()).cumsum()
out = '\n'.join(df.groupby(g)['text'].agg(' '.join))
print (out)

Output=

"My name is raghav #40 @gmail.com

Problem just got complicated $2019 January"

Expected Output=

"My name is raghav

*40

@gmail.com

Problem just got complicated

2019 January"

All are in different lines no matter if they are in same line or not but logically grouped in different lines.

In my understanding maybe we can achieve this by doing these steps:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYHAf.png)
a) Words on same line are grouped if x distance < threshold

b) Words on next line are grouped with previous if y distance < threshold

Threshold is width(image)/ 100; x distance is calculated from **left**; y distance is calculated from top.

Can we do this ?
Let me know if the question is not clear enough!
Thanks!

Added the image i am trying to get the output, data in it is little complicated this i have changed it according to me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use double `join` - with [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) and then for output `Series`:

```
out = '.....'.join(df.groupby('LineNo')['text'].agg(' '.join))
print (out)
My Name is Raghav.....Roll No. # 242
```

Another solution with [`str.cat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.cat.html):

```
out = df.groupby('LineNo')['text'].agg(' '.join).str.cat(sep='.....')
```

EDIT:

```
g = df['LineNo'].ne(df['LineNo'].shift()).cumsum()
out = '.....'.join(df.groupby(g)['text'].agg(' '.join))
print (out)
My Name is Raghav.....Roll No. # 242.....hello the problem just.....got more complicated !!!!
```

Comment: Hi, its working fine for a single page PDF, @jezrael if you can help me with achieving the same thing with 4 page pdf, for your info with every page the "lineNo" is starting from 1 again! So the output i am receiving using this command is concatenating all the texts with number 1 instead my requirement is to get an output for individual lines. Is it possible ? Please reply!

Comment: @RaghavenderRohilla - Yes, check last paragraph from answer `EDIT`.

Comment: Can you tell me in this command "g = df['line_num'].ne(df['line_num'].shift()).cumsum()" what is "ne" ? was searching but not able to find?
Thanks!

Comment: @RaghavenderRohilla - Sure, it is [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html)

Comment: check your gmail @jezrael i have sent some mail.

Comment: I wanted to do some more tweaks in this output, actually this output is coming through a PDF so it is catching the whole line because of which whole line is coming and the output is not making sense, what i am thinking of doing now is to group the text in a meaning full way. For e.g Lets say this output i am getting after running your command into my script(I changed "...." to "\n") 
Output= 
"My name is raghav #40 **gmail.com
Problem just got complicated $2019 January" 

Expected Output=
"My name is raghav
#40
**gmail.com
Problem just got complicated
2019 January" 
Can we do this ?

Comment: @RaghavenderRohilla - Is possible [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54511197/edit) question? Because in comments is bad formating.

Comment: @RaghavenderRohilla - So it is really changed question, I suggest create new (then possible get multiple answers). Also please add how are calculated treshold? Because `Threshold is width(image)/ 100; x distance is calculated from left; y distance is calculated from top.` is not enough information, best is create new expcted column with numbers.

Comment: i am assuming the width its not defined to me, i was just giving ideas for the approach @jezrael, i have added a picture now, if still you may not be able to help i will add this as a new question! 
BTW thanks for help!

Comment: reply so that i can be sure of creating a new question .. ?

Comment: @RaghavenderRohilla - New question is necessary, because original question is a lot changed - edit should be good, if only some small change like your first edit with `g = df['LineNo'].ne(df['LineNo'].shift()).cumsum()
out = '.....'.join(df.groupby(g)['text'].agg(' '.join))
print (out)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54529676/how-to-group-the-sentences-of-output-in-a-readable-format-from-an-excel-tsv-file
This is where i have updated my question please go through it and help if possible! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second concern, maybe try iterating through the column like so.

```
phrase = ""

for i in range(0, df.count):
    if type(df.iat[i, 'text']) == str:
        phrase = phrase + " " + df.iat[i, 'text']
```

To add the space/..., I agree with jezrael, use the str.cat method.